# How to calculate the derivative of inverse $\cot$?

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

For $$y = \cot^{-1}x=\operatorname{arccot}x$$
How can it be proven that
$$\frac {d}{dx} y = -\frac 1 {x^2 + 1}$$
?

Comment: That's because $$\mathrm{arccotan} \ x = \pi/2 - \arctan x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\cot(y)=x$ thus $-cosec^2(y)dy=dx$ so $dy=\frac{dx}{-\ cosec^2(y)}$ but $cot(y)=x$ thus we can write $-csc$ as $-(1+x^2)$ thus we get $dy=\frac{dx}{-(1+x^2)}$. Note the identity $1+\cot^2(x)=\ cosec^2(x)$. Hope you get it now.

Comment: Can you explain the last step? going from $cosec^2(y)$ to $(1+x^2)$?

Comment: See the edit is it clear now?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

If $f,g$ are s.t. $f\circ g=id$, then

$$f(g(x))=x\implies f'(g(x))g'(x)=1.$$
Set $f=cotan$ and $g=arcotan$ and you'll have your answer.

Comment: This is what I went for, but I am missing the last step. If Im not mistaken I got to $g'(x) = -\sin^2(arcot(x))$ and kind of got stuck there.